# working with 2 apps in appium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, appium

I'm automating testing of mobile app. Now I have a problem with following case: user signs up in mobile app.After that he should recieve email with confirmation code and enter it on confirmation page in mobile app.
 I have 2 appium nodes and 2 drivers, one for mobile app and one for browser.So the problem is the following exception when test "came back" to mobile app for code entering

info: [debug] Responding to client with error: {"status":13,"value":{"message":"
An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command.","origValue"
:"Tried to send command to non-existent Android socket, maybe it's shutting down

How I'm doing test: 1) create acc in mobile app 2) open browser 3) open mail 4) get code 5) close browse r 6) trying to enter code....

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Can you retrieve the mail over IMAP, so that you would not need 2 browsers?

Comment: Never thought about that.Thank you for idea! I'll try

Comment: Tried.But it's not a good solution for me because I'm using temp mail account. I was not able to connect to mailinator.com :(

Comment: Mailinator has paid IMAP support. Use a free one: GMail, Yahoo mail, ..., ...